# assigning GameObjects to a list and giving them an index

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

So basically, I have a list with 2 of each number and I want to randomly assign one of those numbers to each card that gets instantiated. It's for a puzzle memory game where u find the matches.

The game is working fine when I have 2 gridRows and 4 gridCols, but if I change the amount of rows or cols then I get: ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index, which prevents me from expanding the game. I tried adding additional numbers to the current list, but that didn't seem to work and also this way doesn't seem very efficient if I want to have a lot of rows and columns

What I want to do is take a list, then shuffle its contents every time I start a match, and then to loop through the indices in order(contents already shuffled) when I instantiate, that's my logic but couldn't make it work for some reason....

can someone help me expand this and find a better way of storing the index please?

here is the code:

```
 public const int gridRows = 2;
public const int gridCols = 4;
public const float offsetX = 4f;
public const float offsetY = 5f;

public MainCard originalCard;
public Sprite[] images;


private void Start()
{
    Vector3 startPos = originalCard.transform.position;
    List<int> numbers = new List<int> { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
    numbers = Shuffle(numbers);

    for (int i = 0; i < gridCols; i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < gridRows; x++)
        {
            MainCard card;
            if (i == 0 && x == 0)
            {
                card = originalCard;
            }
            else
            {
                card = Instantiate(originalCard) as MainCard;
            }

            int index = x * gridCols + i;
            int id = numbers[index];
            card.ChangeSprite(id, images[id]);

            float posX = (offsetX * i) + startPos.x;
            float posY = (offsetX * x) + startPos.y;
            card.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, startPos.z);
        }
    }

    List<T> Shuffle<T>(List<T> cards)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.Count; i++)
        {
            T temp = cards[i];
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, cards.Count);
            cards[i] = cards[randomIndex];
            cards[randomIndex] = temp;
        }

        return cards;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You should not remove your question when someone answers. Stack Overflow is designed to be a searchable repository; people are unlikely to find your question or to understand the answer it you remove your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to cut your project in more parts:

```
using System.Linq;//to Add

public int gridRows = 2;
public  int gridCols = 4;
public List<int> numbers;
public void Start()
{
    int[,] cards = new int[gridRows, gridCols];
    //just put different numbers not needed to duplicate 
    //except if you want to increase the probability
    // to have lot of same number
    numbers = new List<int> { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    InitializeGame(cards);
}

private void InitializeGame(int[,] cards)
{
    //1 you could shuffle your number if you want
    //numbers = Shuffle(numbers);

    //2 you initialize cards to value not used (-1 here)
    for (int r = 0; r < gridRows; r++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < gridCols; c++)
        {
            cards[r, c] = -1;
        }
    }

    // Test if you have filled up all cards
    //Is there again one card with the value -1?
    while (cards.Cast<int>().Any(x => x == -1))
    {
        //3 you pick randomnly a number
        var numCard = numbers[Random.Range(0, numbers.Count)];

        //4 you fill same number to 2 different cards here
        var nbcardTofill = 2;
        while (nbcardTofill != 0)
        {
            //you choose randomny card (row and col) which is free (value = -1) not need but add fun
            var colRandom = Random.Range(0, gridCols);
            var rowRandom = Random.Range(0, gridRows);
            if(cards[rowRandom, colRandom] == -1)
            {
                nbcardTofill--;
                cards[rowRandom, colRandom] = numCard;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now you have the array cards filled with numbers, you could draw the game now..

so you could change number of cols/rows and the list of numbers as you want...

is just one way to program, but i think ist more readable. i have add lot of randomization to add fun...

Another way is to fill sequentially your cards (2 by 2 with same number) and do a shuffle of all cards at the end...

Comment: This is not quite an optimal solution, since by the time most of the grid is filled, you'll spend a lot of time picking random columns/rows that can't be used.

Comment: @AKX,  its just for fun, and it fills 500 x 500 in less of 1 second...

Comment: @Frenchy lol 1 second is huge for an App that should run on 60 fps => max 0.017 seconds per frame ;)

Comment: @Frenchy and I just say that this means nothing ;) If you say less then 0.01 seconds that would be an indicator which makes sense ;)

Comment: sorry like you guess i am french and i have a poor english knowledge...i havent understood the joke!!  you have right  less than 0.01 is better!!

Comment: so i have measured and i arrive at 450 ms for a 500x500 ...so 0.01 is not good...

Comment: well 450 ms is way to much when talking about a framerate based application :) As said for a liquid 60 fps you want want maximum about 17ms per frame. However, this is called in `Start`, only **once** so it is probably fine as a hot fix

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing your loop to iterate over the shuffled numbers rather than the expected grid size. If there aren't enough cards, as it were, some will be left out at the "end" of the grid.

You can then use division and remainder to figure out the correct grid X/Y coordinates for a given card index.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) {
    int y = Math.Floor(i / gridCols);  // the floor is likely redundant but drives the point home
    int x = i % gridCols;
    var card = (i == 0 ? originalCard : Instantiate(originalCard) as MainCard);
    int id = numbers[i];
    card.ChangeSprite(id, images[id]);
    float posX = (offsetX * y) + startPos.x;
    float posY = (offsetY * x) + startPos.y;
    card.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, startPos.z);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Nevermind, as someone said in a comment Random.Range is exclusive with integers

I don't know at all if this could be causing your problem, but I noticed that in your Shuffle method you have this line:

```
int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, cards.Count);
```

In my opinion this could cause an error because the max value in Random.Range is inclusive, so it might be possible that you are generating an unvalid index for some cards.

For example, if you had a list with 5 cards, the maximum index that you would like to generate would be 4, not 5 (which would be the Count).

I would try changing that line to this:

```
int randomIndex = Random.Range(i, cards.Count-1);
```

Comment: `max value in Random.Range is inclusive` => No it is not: [`Random.Range(int, int)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) is `Return a random integer number between min [inclusive] and max [exclusive]`

Comment: You are right derHugo, I noticed that it is inclusive with integers and exclusive with float. I will edit my comment.